# Trouble with compiling and linking OpenCV 3.0.0 in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, makefile

I cloned the new OpenCV 3.0 in active development from `git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git`
and built it with make and then sudo make install. After adding the .dylib files to my project and linking to files in `usr/local` I got code completion for the new functions and objects. Unfortunately when I tried to run it in xcode, I get:

`fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found`

I followed the advice presented in [Clang OS X Lion, cannot find cstdint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116724/clang-os-x-lion-cannot-find-cstdint) but it didn't work.

My os is 10.8.5, xcode 5, and I normally use homebrew on this machine, I have installed a working version of opencv 2.4.7.1 which I did not remove during this process.

Does anyone have experience / advice about building opencv 3.0 directly from the source?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Build Settings of your Project > Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - C++

Change to **libc++**