# OpenCV - 'cstdint' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I'm using Mac 10.10 and OpenCV 3.0, when I was compiling my project I got this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After that, I changed the c++ standard library to libstdc++, another error appeared:

/usr/local/include/opencv2/hal/defs.h:271:14: 'cstdint' file not found

Hope someone could help me

Comment: Please let me know if you solved the issue. I am having same one.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't remember how to fix it. I guess it may be caused by xcode compiler. My Mac has been reinstalled, so I followed this tutorial and it works for me http://mac-opencv-projects.blogspot.com/2014/01/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-1091.html

Answer (score 0):

based on the top answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116724/clang-os-x-lion-cannot-find-cstdint), there are two ways to fix this problem regarding to this fact that you are using of macOs and your default compiler is Clang. You can use:

```
#include <tr1/cstdint>
```

or

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

instead of cstdint, that is a part of libc++.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this when trying to import a header (.h) that was written for C++ into some Objective C code (.m).

The solution for me was to create a middle-ground Objective C++ file (.mm) and header that that imported the C++ header and then exported c-compatible wrapper functions.

The header had something like this in it to make it play nice with Objective-C (.m) code

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

const char *MyNewFunction(void); // or whatever

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

(Credit to [Dave Hylands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821428/dave-hylands) for helping me figure all of that out.)