# Cstdint Missing Error When Installing Pydaedalus with PiP

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, cstdint

I am working on an application which involves route finding (a completely different subject), but for testing I need example mazes to test on. A colleague suggested I use [pydaedalus](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydaedalus/) to generate large scale mazes in the format I need. I am using the following code to try and install the module:

```
$pip3.6 install pydaedalus
```

This returns the following error:

```
-Wno-error=format-security
In file included from daedalus/_maze.cpp:467:
In file included from daedalus/wrapper.h:8:
daedalus/src/util.h:31:10: fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found
#include <cstdint>
             ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have done some research and have found nothing which addresses this. I have also done some (limited) C++ development using cstdint, which has always worked.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116724/clang-os-x-lion-cannot-find-cstdint), but it appears to address a separate issue.
I am developing in OSX 10.10.5

Any help that you can provide is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These compile errors are down to daedalus's requirement of the C++11 standard, which is sometimes a bit tricky to get working on Mac OS X.  One idea might be to check to make sure your Xcode is completely up to date. 
 The page you linked also suggests to try linking against clang's standard library instead of the GCC standard library.  I'm not sure if this will work, or if it will give you linking errors on build or when you import daedalus into python, but you could give it a shot anyway:

```
CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' pip3.6 install pydaedalus
```

Another idea would be to encourage `pip` to use the `clang++` frontend, which your link also suggests might help.  You should be able to set this with the environment variable `CXX` (or, just possibly, `CC`).

```
CXX=clang++ pip3.6 install pydaedalus
```

Try various combinations of those environment settings (e.g., `CXX` and `CFLAGS`), and hopefully something will work eventually.