# C++ program cannot find integer types in cstdint after upgrading MacOS

Tags: c++, clion, macos-high-sierra

Before I upgraded to MacOS High Sierra, this program would correctly print `'Hello, World!'`. Once I upgraded, however, it started failing with the below compiler error. All the compiler settings are still the same.

**Desired outcome:** This code below should print `Hello, World!`

**Error:** output saying that integer types are not declared in the `cstdint` file.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
     return 0;
   }
```

This is the full error message I get:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/joemartinez/Desktop/Test/cmake-build-default --target Test -- -j 6
    Scanning dependencies of target Test
    [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:501,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ios:40,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/iostream:39,
                     from /Users/joemartinez/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:53:11: error: '::int_fast8_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_fast8_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:54:11: error: '::int_fast16_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_fast16_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:55:11: error: '::int_fast32_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_fast32_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:56:11: error: '::int_fast64_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_fast64_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:58:11: error: '::int_least8_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_least8_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:59:11: error: '::int_least16_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_least16_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:60:11: error: '::int_least32_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_least32_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:61:11: error: '::int_least64_t' has not been declared
       using ::int_least64_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:63:11: error: '::intmax_t' has not been declared
       using ::intmax_t;
               ^~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:66:11: error: '::uint8_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint8_t;
               ^~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:67:11: error: '::uint16_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint16_t;
               ^~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:68:11: error: '::uint32_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint32_t;
               ^~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:69:11: error: '::uint64_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint64_t;
               ^~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:71:11: error: '::uint_fast8_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_fast8_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:72:11: error: '::uint_fast16_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_fast16_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:73:11: error: '::uint_fast32_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_fast32_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:74:11: error: '::uint_fast64_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_fast64_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:76:11: error: '::uint_least8_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_least8_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:77:11: error: '::uint_least16_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_least16_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:78:11: error: '::uint_least32_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_least32_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:79:11: error: '::uint_least64_t' has not been declared
       using ::uint_least64_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdint:81:11: error: '::uintmax_t' has not been declared
       using ::uintmax_t;
               ^~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ios:40,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/iostream:39,
                     from /Users/joemartinez/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:1:
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:511:15: error: 'uint_least16_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'uintptr_t'?
           typedef uint_least16_t    int_type;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   uintptr_t
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:584:26: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           to_char_type(const int_type& __c) noexcept
                              ^~~~~~~~
                              off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:587:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:592:25: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           eq_int_type(const int_type& __c1, const int_type& __c2) noexcept
                             ^~~~~~~~
                             off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:592:47: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           eq_int_type(const int_type& __c1, const int_type& __c2) noexcept
                                                   ^~~~~~~~
                                                   off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:595:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:599:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:608:15: error: 'uint_least32_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'uintptr_t'?
           typedef uint_least32_t    int_type;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   uintptr_t
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:681:26: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           to_char_type(const int_type& __c) noexcept
                              ^~~~~~~~
                              off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:684:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:689:25: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           eq_int_type(const int_type& __c1, const int_type& __c2) noexcept
                             ^~~~~~~~
                             off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:689:47: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           eq_int_type(const int_type& __c1, const int_type& __c2) noexcept
                                                   ^~~~~~~~
                                                   off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:692:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:696:24: error: 'int_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'off_type'?
           static constexpr int_type
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            off_type
    In file included from /usr/include/sys/wait.h:110,
                     from /usr/include/stdlib.h:65,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdlib:75,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6391,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/string:52,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ios:42,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/iostream:39,
                     from /Users/joemartinez/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:1:
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:196:2: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int8_t'?
      uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      ^~~~~~~
      u_int8_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:197:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:198:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:199:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:200:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:201:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_wired_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_resident_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:205:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:206:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:210:2: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int8_t'?
      uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      ^~~~~~~
      u_int8_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:211:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:212:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:213:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:214:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:215:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:216:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_wired_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:217:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_resident_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:218:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:219:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:220:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:221:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:222:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:223:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:224:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:225:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:226:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_elapsed_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:230:2: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int8_t'?
      uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      ^~~~~~~
      u_int8_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:231:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:232:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:233:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:234:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:235:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:236:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_wired_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:237:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_resident_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:238:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:239:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:240:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:241:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:242:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:243:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:244:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:245:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:246:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_elapsed_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:247:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_bytesread;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:248:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_byteswritten;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:252:2: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int8_t'?
      uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      ^~~~~~~
      u_int8_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:253:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:254:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:255:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:256:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:257:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:258:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_wired_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:259:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_resident_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:260:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:261:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:262:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:263:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:264:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:265:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:266:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:267:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:268:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_elapsed_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:269:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_bytesread;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:270:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_byteswritten;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:271:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_default;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:272:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_maintenance;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:273:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_background;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:274:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_utility;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:275:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_legacy;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:276:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_user_initiated;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:277:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_user_interactive;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:278:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_billed_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:279:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_serviced_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:283:2: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int8_t'?
      uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];
      ^~~~~~~
      u_int8_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:284:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:285:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:286:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:287:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:288:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:289:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_wired_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:290:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_resident_size;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:291:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:292:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:293:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:294:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_user_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:295:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_system_time;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:296:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pkg_idle_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:297:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_interrupt_wkups;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:298:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_pageins;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:299:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_child_elapsed_abstime;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:300:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_bytesread;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:301:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_diskio_byteswritten;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:302:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_default;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:303:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_maintenance;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t
    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:304:2: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int64_t'?
      uint64_t ri_cpu_time_qos_background;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int64_t

   ...

    /usr/include/sys/resource.h:394:2: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'u_int32_t'?
      uint32_t wm_flags;
      ^~~~~~~~
      u_int32_t
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/rule] Error 2
    make: *** [Test] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you provide us with sample code that fails to compile?

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with cstdint over the years. This is because on different linux's / unixes it's not always there, often users of say, AIX or HP UX may find that they need to use pstdint (portable standard int), however i don't believe that's true in this case, I suspect that your stdint lib is pulled in by other library, such as ctype.h or something like that. Have you tried including stdint.h before you include iostream ?

Comment: Please don't comment your own question. But [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52151483/edit) it to improve it

Comment: Joe: #include <stdint.h> before <iostream> see what happens....

Comment: I think this might be your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872922/broken-c-std-libraries-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13 ... xcode-select --install

Comment: Thanks Owl, I will give it a shot and see if this fixes it, and report back.

Comment: So I i tried the xcode-select --install and all the CLTs seem to be installed and I did an include with <stdint.h> and still no dice. I am in the process of of trying to change the include directory to include-old.

Comment: Digging around further, I also found this, which could be related, I'm not sure if you've tried this yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116724/clang-os-x-lion-cannot-find-cstdint

Comment: Launch the Xcode at least once to complete installation of clang. From that point build tool should start work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it was related to the first post you linked Owl, the fix is to rename the include file in the path usr/local/include => usr/local/include_old. That worked and now everything is compiling. I really do appreciate your time and help, thanks!